# jQuery click function called as soon as page loads

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery script that basically is changing my css when I click a link:

```
jQuery("a.adder").click(css_change());
```

My problem is that when I first load the page, the css_change() is being fired even when the link hasn't been clicked. I know this for sure cause I changed the `css_change()` into `alert("here")` and that alert showed up. Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
css_change()
```

Is immediately executing the function upon binding.

Use:

```
jQuery("a.adder").click(css_change);
```

(pass a reference to the function instead of the results of executing the function).

Comment: so if my css_change() function had parameters, would I have to wrap my css_change(param) in an anonymous function so that it won't be called automatically?

Comment: @Andrew: yes, exactly, something like `jQuery("a.adder").click(function() { css_change(param1, param2); });`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parenthesis on the function call.

```
jQuery("a.adder").click(css_change)
```